# how to define label dimension in memorydata layer in caffe

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I want to define a label of 353 length memorydata layer in caffe, but simple add the name of it doesn't, because the default length of it is 1 (batch_size *1).

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "MemoryData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  memory_data_param {
    batch_size: 60
    channels: 3
    height: 224
    width: 224
  }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

By default if you put toghether data and labels in a single memory layer, caffe assumes that the label is a single integer value (to be used for single label classification for example).

If you need the label to be an array then you should provide labels as a different data layer:

```
layer {
    name: "data"
    type: "MemoryData"
    top: "data"
    top: "useless1"
    include {
        phase: TRAIN
   }
   memory_data_param {
        batch_size: 60
        channels: 3
        height: 224
        width: 224
   }
}

layer {
    name: "label"
    type: "MemoryData"
    top: "label"
    top: "useless2"
    include {
        phase: TRAIN
    }
    memory_data_param {
        batch_size: 60
        channels: 1
        height: 1
        width: 353
   }
}
```

And then in python script fill both vectors before each training step:

```
numpy.copyto(net.blobs['data'].data, yourdata) #Put here your 60x3x224x224 data array
numpy.copyto(net.blobs['label'].data, yourlabels) #Put here your 60x1x1x353 label array
solver.step(1)
```